# How to Save View Controller Data Every Time New Tab Bar Item is Selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have set up a Tab Bar that controls some view controllers in my app. In my view controller CheckViewController, I have user entry-based data that I would like to save every time I am switching from CheckViewController to another view controller. The code I have currently only saves data the first time I switch from CheckViewController to another view controller using the tab bar. I would like to save data every single time CheckViewController is opened and switched to another view controller.

I am currently using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    //code

}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (![viewController isEqual:self]) {

        if ([self.tabBarController.selectedViewController isEqual:self] ) {

            //save data

        }

    }

    return YES;

}
```

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use database wrapper. Just search it in google, I recommend the tutorial on AppCoda.

Comment: I think it's better if you use either `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear` instead of `tabBarController: shouldSelectViewController`

Answer (score 1):

for saving small data,you can use NSUserDefault.
here is an example for saving and reading data.

Save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aData forKey:aKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Read:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:aKey];
```